# Is there a name for this iterative formula for finding near-miss approximations for the square root of X?

Tags: approximation

I noticed a pattern in near-miss approximations for $\sqrt 2$ and eventually figured out a general iterative formula for the square roots of whole numbers:

$\frac {Nn + XDd} {Dn + Nd}$

**Where**

- $X$ = the value we are approximating the square root of
- $N$ = the numerator of the smallest near-miss approximation
- $D$ = the denominator of the smallest near-miss approximation
- $n$ = the numerator of the previous near-miss approximation
- $d$ = the denominator of the previous near-miss approximation

And to confirm, I mean a near-miss as where this is true $n^2 \pm 1 = Xd^2$.

For example:

$\frac 1 1$ is the smallest near-miss approximation for $\sqrt 2$, thus:

$\sqrt 2 \approx \frac{1n + 2d} {1n + 1d}$

Using that formla, the next value is $\frac{(1*1) + (2*1)} {(1*1) + (1*1)} = \frac 3 2$

Thus the next value is $\frac{(1*3) + (2*2)} {(1*3) + (1*2)} = \frac 7 5$

Which eventually makes the sequence

$$\frac 1 1
\frac 3 2
\frac 7 5
\frac {17} {12}
\frac {41} {29}
\frac {99} {70}...$$

Similarly $\frac 8 3$ is the smallest near-miss approximation for $\sqrt 7$

$\sqrt 7 \approx \frac{8n + 21d} {3n + 8d}$

$$\frac 8 3
\frac {127} {48}
\frac {2024} {765}
\frac {32257} {12192}...$$

This definitely isn't the best formula, as you must find the smallest near-miss to start with and it obviously doesn't really work with whole number square roots - $\sqrt 4$, $\sqrt 9$, $\sqrt 16$, etc., but it seems to work for all numbers I've tested.

Is there a name for this formula, or is it a specialized subset of something else?

Comment: @WillJagy That seems to be related to the formula I found, but requires the difference between $n^2$ and $Xd^2$ to always be either 1 or -1.  It also requires you plug and check to find each value.